# Ruby loading required items error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I'm trying to run the script from "[HOW TO RUN YOUR OWN BITCOIN ARBITRAGE BOT](https://www.uludum.org/courses/118-how-to-run-your-own-bitcoin-arbitrage-bot/subsections/2164-installation)".

You can try following it yourself and test the results.

I followed it exactly and yet, when I open the program, I get this and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
c:\Ruby200-x64\devkit>rbtc_simple
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require
': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
5:in `require'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rbtc_arbitrage_simple-2.1.1
/lib/rbtc_arbitrage.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
5:in `require'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
5:in `require'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rbtc_arbitrage_simple-2.1.1
/bin/rbtc_simple:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rbtc_simple:23:in `load'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rbtc_simple:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm running 64bit Ruby and 64bit devkit.

I ran `git init` in C:\Ruby200\bin, which I think is the right folder. How can I know where to run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `bundler` gem as seen in your error message:

`require: cannot load such file -- bundler`

to fix this you can install bundler to your gems: `gem install bundler`

Comment: Did you run `gem install rbtc_arbitrage` ?

Comment: Yes I have ran that command. Just reran it incase still same error so it looks:http://pastebin.com/gpGqTTfB

Comment: `gem install rbtc_arbitrage_simple` will give you `rbtc_simple` - so you should have `rbtc` with `gem install rbtc_arbitrage` - in otherwords - try `gem install rbtc_arbitrage_simple` to get `rbtc_simple` command working

Comment: you should run a `bundle install` to get all the gems necessary for the project.

Comment: this seems to be a problem with bundler - and universal gems using ruby 2.0 - you can either use an older version of ruby or just install the gems individually - so now according to your error message: `gem install bitstamp` - then run `bundle install` again, and read the next error . . . not the best but it should get you there.

Comment: c:\Ruby200-x64\bin>gem install bitstamp
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.
0.0/x64-mingw32/openssl.so
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Comment: are you running minggw? (http://www.mingw.org/) - you will need to be running in this to get the mingw32 version of bitstamp working. In general - Ruby on windows is not easy to setup.

Comment: Did it in a virtual machine. Works fine in linux. Typical. thanks anyway.